# Cone in algebraic geometry: useful construction?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $S$ be a scheme. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a quasi-coherent graded $\mathcal{O}_S$-algebra. Assume that $\mathcal{O}_ S = \mathcal{A}_0$. The affine cone associated to $\mathcal{O}_S$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is the $S$-scheme $C:= \underline{\mathop{\mathrm{Spec}}}_ S(\mathcal{A})$. I understand the definition and my geometric intuition is that it generalizes the geometric construction of a "ray" space of projective space; nevertheless I'm far away from fully comprehending what are the advantages and usage of the cone construction in algebraic geometry.

Which kind of problems can be conceptually attacked effectively using this construction and what is the intuition making it a useful tool one should have? Is it more than an introducing model example of Grothendieck's relative point of view?

Can its role in algebraic geometry be compared with the role of cone construction in topology? In that setting a cone provides a space, which contains the original space, but has a bunch of nice topological properties, which making it interesting for homotopy theory.

In algebraic geometry we have also a zero section $i_0: S \to C$. The point is: what is the bunch of properties making the cone in a certain way easier to work with (possibly like better control over regularity, certain nice properties for birational geometry, from intersection theoretical viewpoint, and so on, I don't know; to gather at least the most important ones is precisely the motivation for posting this question), while on the other hand keeping enough information about the original space that we can draw back conclusions about it (and so that justify its advantages)?

Comment: It is way too philosophical, but let me make some remarks. First, let us specialize to the simplest case that $S$ is affine. In this case, $C$ is no more than just the ordinary $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ where $A$ is a graded $S$-algebra with the 0th piece being $S$. This is more or less the affine cone associated to a projective variety.

Comment: I don't see how this could be related to mapping cones in algebraic topology. I understand mapping cones simply as homotopy cofibers. In the algebraic geometric case, the affine cone along with the graded structure is just more informative than the underlying scheme of a projective variety.

Comment: As far as I understand, the magic of this construction appears at the passage from ordinary objects to graded objects, rather than the one you are trying to figure out. For example, let $A$ be a commutative ring and $I\subseteq A$ be an ideal, then we have the blowup algebra $\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty I^n$ and the associated graded algebra $\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty I^n/I^{n+1}$ (the conormal algebra). What should be understood deeply is that this step could be used to analyze the singularity along $I$.

Comment: @Yai0Phah:this looks like a point I was looking for. for example assume that $A$ has singularities along $I$ and we want to study them. then I can construct the blowup algebra $\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty I^n$ and conormal algebra $\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty I^n/I^{n+1}=(\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty I^n)/I$ over $A$, as you said. which advantages & new tools or methods arise in order to study the singularities when we consider these two constructions, instead of working with "old" $A$.